# Javascript nth-child not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a grid which is made up of divs and each row has following structure

```
<div role="row" style="position: relative; height:25px;" id="row0agent">
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 0px; z-index: 799; width:28px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Bansal, Sumeet">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Bansal, Sumeet</div>
</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 381px; z-index: 793; width:99px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="0">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">0</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 480px; z-index: 792; width:42px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="BTS">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">BTS</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 522px; z-index: 791; width:35px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="BANSALS1">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">BANSALS1</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 557px; z-index: 790; width:56px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="10013">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">10013</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 613px; z-index: 789; width:49px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Amit Saha">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Amit Saha</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 662px; z-index: 788; width:28px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="HQ">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">HQ</div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 690px; z-index: 787; width:63px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Kausik ">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Kausik </div>
</div>
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 753px; z-index: 786; width:63px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="UNASSIGNED">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">UNASSIGNED</div>
</div>
```

I have to make some of the jqx-grid-cells red as per the business logic. Now as you can see from html there is no proper way of accessing each item as they don't have unique id.
So I decided to get each row by id and get its nth child to make that grid as red. 
So for testing when I execute below code from console its working fine

```
$("#row0agent :nth-child(2)").css("color","red");
```

and the 2nd child of row0agent is getting red.

Now when I am looping through the grid its behaving strange

```
$("#row"+i+"agent :nth-child("+j+")").css("color","red");
```

In the above case $("#row"+i+"agent") is working properly it is selecting proper row but nth-child("+j+") is giving wrong selection.

Instead of selecting

```
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 28px; z-index: 798; width:35px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Available">
<div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Available</div>
```

It is selecting entire row.

Since `i` and `j` are integer I used `toString()` as well but it didn't work.

Comment: This code is kinda pain to read, can you saparate CSS from HTML? Or make a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mistake is here

```
<div role="row" style="position: relative; height:25px;" id="row0agent">
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 0px; z-index: 799; width:28px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Bansal, Sumeet">
    <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Bansal, Sumeet</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here You ended main DIV . So Your code dont work. Because, compiler understand that , there is only 1 div is in id row0agent. so, it cant read 2nd child.

The working code is

```js
$("#row0agent :nth-child(2)").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="row" style="position: relative; height:25px;" id="row0agent">
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 0px; z-index: 799; width:28px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Bansal, Sumeet">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Bansal,Sumeet</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 381px; z-index: 793; width:99px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="0">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">0</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 480px; z-index: 792; width:42px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="BTS">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">BTS</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 522px; z-index: 791; width:35px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="BANSALS1">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">BANSALS1</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 557px; z-index: 790; width:56px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="10013">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">10013</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 613px; z-index: 789; width:49px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Amit Saha">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Amit Saha</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 662px; z-index: 788; width:28px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="HQ">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">HQ</div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 690px; z-index: 787; width:63px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="Kausik ">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">Kausik </div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 753px; z-index: 786; width:63px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item" title="UNASSIGNED">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 4px;">UNASSIGNED</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this :

```
$("#row0agent .jqx-grid-cell:eq(2)").css("color","red");
```

It's meant you will select the third tag has jqx-grid-cell class in  tag has row0agent id

Answer (score 0):

It can be this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i =0;
    for(j=2;j<10;j+=3)
      $("#row"+i+"agent .jqx-grid-cell").eq(j).css("background-color","red");

 });
```

working fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kodedsoft/kuuswn0a/

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that because you have a space in it, `#row0agent :nth-child(2)` is saying

1. Find the node with *id "row0agent"*
2. Then **for *all* descendent nodes** (the space), not just immediate children
3. If it is the `2`nd node (has only 1 previous sibling)
4. Select this node

Therefore, if you were to do it with `:nth-child(1)`, you would see *"the entire row"* selected, as every `.jqx-grid-cell-left-align` you've shown is a first child. I'm guessing this is the case you're seeing as unexpected behaviour - you didn't actually give `i` and `j` values

---

Instead, try with a child specific selector `>`; `#row0agent > :nth-child(2)`, or in your general case,

```
$("#row" + i + "agent > :nth-child(" + j + ")").css("color", "red");
```

---

It may also be visually easier to see which node has been selected if you use a *border* instead of text colour

```js
var i = 0,
    j = 1; // !important to prove it is not matching other nodes too
$("#row" + i + "agent > :nth-child(" + j + ")").css("border", "2px solid red", "!important");
j = 2;
$("#row" + i + "agent > :nth-child(" + j + ")").css("border", "2px solid green");
j = 3;
$("#row" + i + "agent > :nth-child(" + j + ")").css("border", "2px solid blue");
j = 4;
$("#row" + i + "agent > :nth-child(" + j + ")").css("border", "2px solid yellow");
```

```css
#row0agent > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row0agent">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```